# remoting call from javascript appends extra parameter to the URL

Tags: controller, javascript-remoting

I have a remoting method called from a controller which is given below

```
@RemoteAction
public static PageReference openLocatorPage(String addressId){
    Address__c addr = [SELECT Id, Name, Latitude__c, Longitude__c FROM Address__c WHERE Id = :addressId];
    Decimal latitude = addr.Latitude__c;
    Decimal longitude = addr.Longitude__c;
    String urlLocatorPage = '/apex/LeadLocator?lat='+latitude+'&lon='+longitude;
    PageReference pr = new PageReference(urlLocatorPage);
    return pr;
}
```

and my code in javascript using this controller is

```
LeadLocatorPreProcessorControllerV2.openLocatorPage($scope.CustomerSite.AddressID,function(results,event){
    console.log(results);
    //window.open(results,"_self");
});
```

Now the problem I am facing is that my url should be

`/apex/LeadLocator?lat=1234&lon=1234`

but instead my URL comes out to be

`/apex/LeadLocator?lat=1234&amp;lon=1234`

any help regarding this amp; being appended to my URl would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `&amp;` is the HMTL entity equivalent of the ampersand character.

I'm afraid that I don't have anything on hand that I can test this with, but after looking through the documentation on javascript remoting, I came across [Configuring a JavaScript Remoting Request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_configuring_request.htm).

There is an `escape` parameter that defaults to true. This could be what is responsible for escaping your ampersand.

If that is the case, then you should be able to disable the HTML escaping by passing a configuration object as the third parameter to the remote method call and setting the `escape` value to `false`.

```
LeadLocatorPreProcessorControllerV2.openLocatorPage(
    $scope.CustomerSite.AddressID,
    function(results,event){
        console.log(results);
        //window.open(results,"_self");
    },
    {'buffer': true, 'escape': false, 'timeout': 30000 }
);
```

Comment: This will almost certainly fix the issue.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `PageReference` instead of just returning a simple url as `String` from the RemoteAction? This isn't the first time that I saw this.

Comment: @smukov About the only thing that I can think of is that using `PageReference` will automatically URL-encode the query string. You can also call an `@RemoteAction` annotated method via apex just like any other method, so perhaps it's being used elsewhere.

Comment: @DerekF Hmm, good points. Thank you for this information.